# Php url rewrriting empty links

Tags: html, apache, url-rewriting, hyperlink

i'm trying to rewirting urls, it's ok but all links with href "#" goes to a page.

here is my url rewriting;

```
     RewriteEngine on
     ReWriteRule ^index$ index.php [L,NC]
     ReWriteRule ^groups/(.*) groupdetail.php?groupid=$1
```

and this is an ordinary link which goes to login.php, all urls go to login.php

```
  <a href="#">Settings</a>
```

Comment: You mean it's staying on the same page? Can you clarify what the problem is?

Comment: Nope, it should stay on the same page(groups.php) but it goes to login.php

Comment: Can you show which URL you are visiting when you are clicking that link and where the link takes you?

Comment: it shows "go to www.site.com/#" not "www.site.com/groups/1#"

Comment: As said - which URL are you on when you are clicking that link? What does the browser's address bar say?

Comment: http://127.0.0.1/site/groups/1 this page im on

Comment: Huh? That's weird. The browser shouldn't be doing that. Are you 10000% sure you are on that page? What browser are you in? Are you 10000% sure the link doesn't read `<a href='/#'>`? Are you using a `<base>` tag somewhere in your code?

Comment: yea, i have base tag cause avodinig css files from url rewrite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> yea, i have base tag cause avodinig css files from url rewrite

The `<base>` tag is your problem: It is rewriting all your relative links on the page, including `#`.

This is one reason why I hate `<base>` with a passion. If at all possible, consider using absolute URLs to address your style sheets instead:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" src="/css/styles.css">
```

Comment: are there any other way for css files without base tag? What do you mean with absolute URLs?